# Unable to drawTextInRect with UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, quartz-graphics

I want to draw a UILabel onto my cell. I don't want to add it as a subview for performance reasons. I am doing the following:

```
-(void)drawContent
{
    usernameLabel.text = [message valueForKey:@"user_login"];
    usernameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12];
    usernameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [usernameLabel drawTextInRect:CGRectMake(77, 5, 200, 20)];
}
```

but I get a ton of errors:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetTextMatrix: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFontSize: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetTextPosition: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances: invalid context 0x0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw an UILabel, just create and add the UILabel to the cells contentView within the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

There is no need to call `drawTextInRect:` directly. This only should be used on subclassing UILabel cell and overwriting that method with an alternative implementation. Calling the method directly as in your code causes these errors, because the system has not setup the graphics context to draw to.

**EDIT** Update with sample reference:

If you want to draw a table's cell on your own, check the [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) provided by Apple. In there you will finde the 5_CustomTableViewCell/Classes/TimeZoneView which is used as a content subview for the 5_CustomTableViewCell/Classes/TimeZoneCell. The TimeZoneView shows how to draw your custom text directly to the view without using an UILabel.

Comment: I don't want to add the UILabel to the content view for performance reasons. How can I draw the text itself?

Comment: @Sheehan I updated my answer with a link to [Apple's TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), which can be downloaded and shows how to draw custom text to support fast cell scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You should really call *any* drawing methods in a UIView's `drawRect:` implementation. If I remember correctly, UITableViewCells used to support drawing directly where you could do the following in your UITableViewCell subclass:

```
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
    [self drawContent];
}
```

This is now a discouraged practice for a variety of reasons. However, you can still create a custom UIView subclass which draws the actual cell content, add it to the cell's `contentView` and have it implement `drawRect:` inside which you send `drawTextInRect:`. That will work as expected.

Comment: Can you link me to a sample project that does this? I seem to be completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried using drawTextInect, but you can try this way:

```
 cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, cell.frame.size.width,   cell.frame.size.height)];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cellLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cellLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
cellLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];
```

Hope this help!!

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding subviews as that is expensive. drawTextInRect is supposed to keep the view hierarchy flat for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the method's [`documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILabel/drawTextInRect%3a)?

This method is only for subclassing and you are getting the errors because there is no drawing context defined and this pertain's to the `UILabel` instance and not where `drawContent` is being called. If you wish to draw a text in a different view then use an `NSString` instance. It provides [`drawing extensions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: NSString doesn't have drawing extensions for iOS.

Comment: @Sheehan It does. Updated the answer with the correct link. As such you can use methods ranging from [`drawAtPoint:withFont:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint:withFont:) to `drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me an example of how to use it? It returns a CGSize. I'm not exactly sure how that will draw the text?

Comment: You can ignore the return value if you need. [`Here`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/StringRender.zip) is a quick sample.

Comment: @Sheehan Did the sample help ?